# sqlite withdraw/deposit function in python

Tags: python, sqlite, banking

The last stretch of my banking project I've been working on is the deposit/withdraw function. I've gotten most of the other bits working (outside of cleaning up the code) I'm not fully understanding how one adds and subtracts a number from a sql statement inside of python...so here's the part of the code I'm struggling with:
here are my tables:

```
sqlite_file  = 'banking2_db.sqlite'
table_1      = 'Bartertown'
table_2      = 'PINs'
id_column    = 'Card_Numbers'
column_1     = 'Character_PINs'
column_2     = 'Balances'
column_3     = 'Card_Numbers'
column_4     = 'Characters'
```

class LoginPrompt:
    def Login(self):
        while True:
            print(menu[1])
            self.Card_number=str(input('>>  '))
            print(menu[2])

```
        while True:
            try:
                self.Character_PINs = getpass.getpass('>>  ')
                self.one_row = c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn} WHERE {cn}=? and {cnn}=?'.\
                            format(tn=table_1, cn=column_1, cnn=column_3), (self.Character_PINs, self.Card_number,))
                for row in self.one_row.fetchone():
                    print('Welcome: ', row)
                    input('Press any key to continue... ')
                    return
            except:
                    print('PIN incorrect; try again')
                    break 
            #MINOR ISSUE, ONLY QUERIES CHAR COLUMN
def loginMenu(self):
    while True:
        print(menu[5])
        print("\n1 - Deposit funds")
        print("2 - Withdraw funds")
        print("3 - Check balance")
        print("4 - Reset Pin")
        print("5 - Exit")            

        while True:
            try:
                choice = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please choose a valid entry")
            if choice >= 1 and choice <=5:              
                choice == 1:
                    amount = input("\nPlease enter the deposit amount: ")
                    if amount != '' and amount.isdigit():
                        int(amount)

                        balance = c.execute('UPDATE {tn} SET {cn} = Balances +:amount WHERE Card_Numbers =:self.Card_number' .\
                                      format(tn=table_1, cn=column_2,))
                        new_bal = balance + (int(amount))
                        print('${} has been deposited to account {} and the new balance is ${}'.\
                              format(amount, self.Card_number, balance + (int(amount))))
                        for row in self.Balances.fetchone():
                            print('Your new balance is: ', new_bal)
                            return self.loginMenu()
```

basically, I'm trying to make sure the program can only pull the balance where the PIN and the Card Number are specified. It selects the balance (This part is working, it is another option in the menu) however, the UPDATE function is still a mystery to me. I understand how to update both the ENTIRE column...on accident, and also how to change the value presented in the Balance field to the value the user submitted ie: the user selects to deposit 100 caps, and then their balance becomes 100 caps. The column I'm trying to update is called Balances, Card_Numbers is the column containing the users "credit card" and amount is the value the user just entered.
 Thank you for your help.

edit: added tables, and initial input of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the column `Balances` then your statement should be:

```
...SET Balances = Balances + :amount...
```

so do it like this:

```
c.execute("UPDATE " + table_1 + " SET Balances = Balances + ? WHERE Card_Numbers = ?", (amount, self.Card_number,))
```

Comment: all I'm getting now is a syntax error,  will report back in a bit.

Comment: I'm not getting anything much better. keep getting a syntax error near "."

Comment: @cooperalan I thought that your code was syntactically correct but did not do the update.Try the edited code. This code updates the table.

Comment: No it's a very simple sql statement. Try it without the loop.

Comment: i'll try that, give me a bit. and thank you for the help.

Comment: i'm pretty sure earlier in the code (specifically the first while true statement should have a connection close, and that's why I'm getting the error that the db is locked? I'm gonna keep poking around, you've been a huge help though. thank you.

Comment: i switched it out from amount being an input statement to just '100' for simplicity, now I'm getting a "nonetype is not iterable"

Comment: You are doing something wrong in the loop. Check this: https://errorcodespro.com/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable/

Comment: I think you're right. I'm checking it out now. either nonetype or db is locked...crap. thanks your your help man.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, silly me.

```
            choice == 1:
                amount = input("\nPlease enter the deposit amount: ")
                if amount != '' and amount.isdigit():
                    int(amount)

                    balance = c.execute('UPDATE {tn} SET {cn} = Balances +:amount WHERE Card_Numbers =:self.Card_number' .\
                                  format(tn=table_1, cn=column_2,))
                    new_bal = balance + (int(amount))
```

I was trying to reference it by printing the output of the of the db while it hadn't been committed yet, :eyeroll:
Thank you for the help forpas, it worked like a charm.